# How to filter product by specific attribute in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, product-collection

I want to filter a collection of products by product (brand) attribute, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to use product  **CollectionFactory**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Yourmodule\Block;
class ProductCollection extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,        
        array $data = []
    )
    {    
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;    
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
         $collection->addAttributeToFilter('brand_id', array('eq' => 'brand_value'));

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Load product collection with specific attribute**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');

$collection = $productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('brand', array('eq' => "brandcode"));    
foreach ($collection as $product) {
    print_r($product->getData());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add filter like this..

```
protected $_product;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
) {
    $this->_product = $product;
}

public function execute()
{
    $productCollection = $this->_product->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('brand', array('eq' => 'test'));
}
```

- You can change your condition in array here I've added condition for Brand = Test. You can put `neq` instead of `eq` so then that will work like Brand != Test.
  Hope this will helphul to you!

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory */
protected $collectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
) {
    $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
}

public function yourMethod()
{
    // Use factory to create a new product collection
    $productCollection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
    /** Apply filters here */
    $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('brand', 'value_here')

    foreach ($productCollection as $product){
         echo 'Name  =  '.$product->getName().'<br>';
    }  
}
```

Hope you help this ;)

Comment: Shafeel Sha, thanks for answer, I want to get it in my custom module, what class do I need to inject for _pct?  for \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory it doesn't work

Comment: check updated answer